# Why variable doesn't change it's value when used in a Parse query inside a loop

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform

> My problem is as follows: I have an argument class where all arguments have a parentId which are indeed objectId of other arguments. I would like to write a query where I can get a list of all arguments that are connected to each other with this kind of parent-child relationship. So i have tried this..

```
class ArgumentViewController: UIViewController {

var all = [String]()
var temporaryId = "vEKV1xCO09"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    for _ in 1...3 {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Argument").whereKey("objectId", equalTo: temporaryId)
        
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            if let arguments = objects {
                for argument in arguments {
                    self.all.append(argument["parentId"] as! String)
                    print(self.all)
                    self.temporaryId = argument["parentId"] as! String
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

> but the problem is temporaryId inside the loop does not update itself. It remains the same in all iterartions. Hence when i do print(self.all) i simply get an array of 3 strings which all are parent of my initial argument
>
> My goal is to get an array that is [parent of my initial argument, parent of parent of my initial argument, parent of parent of parent of my ...]
>
> I have searched similar topics but couldn't find a solution. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: So your problem is that self.temporaryId  = argument["parentId"] as! String doesn't change from "vEKV1xCO09" to something else is that right?

Comment: thats exactly correct

Comment: I figured out the reason why but still couldn't find a solution for it. Apparently, since "findObjectsInBackground" is an asynchronous query and therefore main thread runs before the query reaches a conclusion. I tried using "findObjects" instead of "findObjectsInBackground" which gives me the array i was looking for but slows down UI significantly giving me a "A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread" warning.

Answer (score 0):

Since `query.findObjectsInBackground` runs in background thread, there is no way to update `temporaryId` with the newly retrieved `@"parentId"` in every `for` loop.

So I guess you could create a recursive function, something like:

```
func getParentId() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Argument").whereKey("objectId", equalTo: temporaryId)

    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        if let arguments = objects {
            for argument in arguments {
                self.all.append(argument["parentId"] as! String)
                print(self.all)
                self.temporaryId = argument["parentId"] as! String
                while (all.count <= 3) {
                    getParentId()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't done enough practice  in Swift as i'm an Objective-C developer, so I'm sorry if I made some syntax errors.